# set constant values for cuisine like Chinese,Indian in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I want to use Cuisines like (Chinese, Indian, US) as constant values in my application which are defined in a config file.  How can I set as constants and how can access in controllers?

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly not an answer to your question, but a suggestion that you look for alternatives.  I think you would be far better off creating a database table with your cuisine names in it than to use constants.  Leverage rails associations so that you can write nice readable code.

The problem with using constants is that under many circumstances, they aren't really constant.  What happens if you want to add Japanese?  What happens if you want to add Thai, but then 6 months later decide to drop it?  What happens if you decide that Indian is too broad, and you want "Northern Indian" and "Southern Indian"?

With a database table, you can ensure that the class that are associated with those constants are always in a consistent state.  When you need to get them all, they are just a line of code away with

```
my_cuisines = Cuisine.all
```

with nice built in iterators.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider what Marc Talbot said. Make sure that you really don't want a normal database model. If you're sure you want to use constants then continue on:

My preferred way to do this is with a pseudo-model.

In `app/models/cuisine.rb`

```rb
class Cuisine

  # Should come before the constant declarations
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  Mexican = new('Mexican')
  Chinese = new('Chinese')
  Indian = new('Indian')

  def to_s
    name
  end

  # other related methods
  # like translations, descriptions, etc.

end
```

Then in the everywhere else in the app you can just reference `Cuisine::Mexican` or `Cuisine::Indian`

Also depending on how you are using it you might need a list of the cuisines.

```rb
class Cuisine

  ...

  def self.all
    [Mexican, Indian, Chinese, ...]
  end
end
```

This technique keeps the code organized and keeps you from writing yet another initializer file.

Comment: You may wish to put the initialize method to the top.  Otherwise the constant declarations will fail (since there is no initializer set, rails is not expecting the string argument).

Comment: Ah, good catch. I've changed the example. My brain was thinking in JS where functions/vars are hoisted to the top of the scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem 'settingslogic'

model settings.rb:

```
class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{Rails.root}/config/settings.yml"
  namespace Rails.env
end
```

then, use in controller:

```
Settings.cousines
```

Comment: I want to use  from config file, environment.rb